# Integrating a script within CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html

Currently on my style sheet I have the following:

```
a {
box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #AFFFFF;
}
```

This creates a fake custom underline.

I want it so that every time the page is loaded or refreshed the color of the border changes to a random color specified in the array.

I found this script here a little while ago:

```
var colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'];
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
document.getElementById('title').style.color = random_color;
```

How do I go about doing this the right way?

Answer (score 2):

In your example you are using javascript to set the text colour every time that script is executed. You can simply change it to set the boxshadow every time instead.

Note: css properties with a hyphen (-) in are converted to camelCase; `box-shadow` becomes `boxShadow`

```js
var colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'];
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
document.getElementById('title').style.boxShadow = "inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 "+random_color;
```

```css
a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #AFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<a id="title">test</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a **random class** to the element, with the classes associated with different colors:

CSS:

```
a.red {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 red;
}
a.blue {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3fw 0 0 blue;
}
a.yellow {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3fw 0 0 yellow;
}
```

And your JS:

```
var classes = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
var random_class = classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)];
var title = document.getElementById('title');
classes.forEach((el) => {
   title.classList.remove(el);
});
title.classList.add(random_class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use styles this way. I would predefine classes in CSS file and assign those classes to elements.