# Animating left to right underline using box-shadow

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I go about animating a fake box-shadow underline that have under my the link? I would like to have the underline go from left to right.

I am using a script that changes the color of the underline everything that it loads the page it alternates between three colors.

I have tried to add "animation: stretchRight;" to a.red, a.blue, a.yellow, but it does not seem to work.

I can use the use the stretchRight class to other elements so I know that works well. I believe it has something to do with the script.

Below is the code I am working on.

Can anyone of you wizards help me with this problem?

```css
body {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 margin: 0px;

}

.container {
 display: block;
 width: 85%;
 /*center vertically & horizontally*/
 position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#wotd {
 text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
    clear: none;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
    animation: fadein 2s;
}

a, a:visited, a:hover {
 /*display: block; this makes the whole line justified*/
 -ms-text-align-last: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
 text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
 
}

a.red {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #DB3069;
}

a.yellow {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #fffd35;
}

a.blue {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #00f9ff;
} 


@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}


/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
    @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}


/* This is WiP */
     

@keyframes stretchRight {
    0% {
        transform: scaleX(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }                           
}

@-webkit-keyframes stretchRight {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    }       
}

#object {
    display: block;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    visibility: visible;
}


.eee {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #00f9ff;
    animation: stretchRight;
    -webkit-animation: stretchRight;  

    animation-duration: 1s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-out;    
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;    

    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="wotd">blah blah blueee<a id="decor" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692808/integrating-a-script-within-css">pew pew paw</a></div>
   <div id="object" class="eee"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var classes = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
  var random_class = classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)];
  var title = document.getElementById('decor');
  classes.forEach((el) => {
     title.classList.remove(el);
  });
  title.classList.add(random_class);
 </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the animation on the link itself and the `@keyframes` must specify the CSS property you want to animate.

```js
  var classes = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
  var random_class = classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)];
  var title = document.getElementById('decor');
  classes.forEach((el) => {
     title.classList.remove(el);
  });
  title.classList.add(random_class);
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 margin: 0px;

}

.container {
 display: block;
 width: 85%;
 /*center vertically & horizontally*/
 position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#wotd {
 text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
  clear: none;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

a, a:visited, a:hover {
 /*display: block; this makes the whole line justified*/
 -ms-text-align-last: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
 text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
 
}

a.red {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #DB3069;
}

a.yellow {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #fffd35;
}

a.blue {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #00f9ff;
} 

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}   

@keyframes stretchRight {
    0% {
        transform: scaleX(0);
        border-bottom:none;
    }

    100% {
        transform: scaleX(1);
        border-bottom:1px solid black;
    }                           
}

#decor { 
         animation-duration: 3s;
         animation-name: stretchRight; 
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
   <div id="wotd">blah blah blueee<a id="decor" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692808/integrating-a-script-within-css">pew pew paw</a></div>
   <div id="object" class="eee"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. I want the fake-colored-underline to be animated from left to right. I did not want add a new black underline under the link itself.

Comment: The line is animated in this code. Also, what exactly did you want underlined?

Comment: You have added border-bottom:none; and border-bottom:1px solid black;. I do not want to user border-bottom to make the underline.  I am using box-shadow to draw the border. Do you see the thick colored line over the text? that is what I want to be animated.